# Setting up DataGridView with subrows when row is selected

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am doing a WinForms app for personal use. In this app, I have a `DataGridView` in which I display some data from a database. Lets say this data is about a person like first & last names, date of birth, adress, etc.

Then, each person can have orders. These orders split up into description, quantity, price, total price.

What I want is a `DataGridView` that looks something like this:

[image]

I searched the web but could only find custom controls that were paid. As I am doing this for a learning project, I want to stay in the free range.

Comment: Unfortunately the `DataGridView` control for WinForms is pretty limited when it comes to customization.  You may have more luck with some TreeList controls.  And now I see someone has posted the CodeProject link i was going to refer you to =)

Comment: It's a little strange that a `DataGrid` can do this kind of job while a `DataGridView` can't.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing here, have you had any luck finding a grid capable of doing this ?

Comment: no I think I just did it with a pop-up form that contained a table with the entry's sub-values...dunno where I put that though :(

Answer (score 1):

I used TreeListView from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3225/TreeListView)

Comment: The only problem with that is the fixed column headers. I need different headers for my pop up rows.